# Training accuracy is not improving in recognizing violence with CNN + LSTM

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, lstm, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a violence recognizer with CNN + LSTM but when I train the model it produces the same accuracy over the epochs as the following picture 55% over 20 epochs [Right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efTn2.png)
The data consists of 100 videos violence/non violence from the hockey dataset and it was preprocessed by cropping dark frames, scaled pixel values [0 to 1] and normalized in which the mean is zero with same standard deviation. The input shape is (100, 20, 160, 160, 3) which is number of videos, frames per video, frame height, frame width, RGB channels respectively. And the labels tensor of shape (100,2) which represents a vector [0 1] or [1 0] both arrays are given into the model as floats
The code of the model

```
def CNN_LSTM():

input_shapes=(NUMBER_OF_FRAMES,IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE,3)
np.random.seed(1234)
vg19 = tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19 
base_model=vg19(include_top=False,weights='imagenet',input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE,3))
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

cnn = TimeDistributed(base_model,  input_shape=(NUMBER_OF_FRAMES, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))


model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(NUMBER_OF_FRAMES, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS)))
model.add(cnn)
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))


model.add(LSTM(NUMBER_OF_FRAMES , return_sequences= True))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(90)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(2, activation="sigmoid"))

adam = Adam(lr=0.01)


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=["accuracy"])

return model

x = CNN_LSTM()
x.summary()
history = x.fit(fvideo,flabels, batch_size=10, epochs=15)`
```

How can I solve the problem of the same accuracy? Thanks in advance

Comment: With this model, you should be using a softmax activation at the output layer, and categorical cross-entropy loss.

Comment: that did not solve the problem